# response error from ajax http post crossdomain request with json

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, http, post

I am using asp.net and on client side in javascript and I try to make an ajax HTTP request:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        crossDomain: true,
        data: trip,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (responseData, textStatus) {
            var value = responseData.someKey;
        },
        error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('POST failed.');
        }
    });
```

on the other side i have an azurecloud project and this method (c#):

```
[ActionName("test")]
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Test([FromBody] SetTripRequestEntity trip)
{
    return Ok("year it works!");
}
```

If I run the code, the server jumps into the c# method and the trip has the correct object, so everything is fine.
But after he returns Ok("year it works!"); on the javascript side he runs into the error function:
responseData is an object with nulls and 0 parameters,
textStatus is "error"  (really only "error" not more)
errorThrown is ""

I don't understand why he does not go to the success function.
I have tried to make the request in fiddler2 and there I got the right answer.
So the problem is at the javascript (ajax) side.

does somebody know how to run it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Arent you supposed to use JSONP in cross domain requests? @http://bob.ippoli.to/archives/2005/12/05/remote-json-jsonp/

Comment: Have a look at the HTTP request/response in a browser's dev tools: like https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/index#improving-network-performance

Comment: You may need to add support for CORS to your api, see this article: http://bit.ly/1xP4MBl

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answers! If I understand it right, I have to change stuff at the server side if I use jsonp, but that is no option for me, because the server is running currently and to change stuff there would be my last option.

Comment: I mean, I don't need to do that in ajax... I only need to speak with the server from the javascript side. And if I use XMLHttpRequest I have the problem with the cross domain. But with the ajax I got an answer on the server side so I think I'am on the right way, only the response from the server to the ajax request does not work